# JustAudio Battery Usage and Audio Offload

Tags: exoplayer, just-audio

I am concerned about the battery usage of ExoPlayer, and their suggestion to use audio offload when playing longer streams. Their documentation says that audio offload is in experimental phase.

I recently saw that just_audio upgraded to ExoPlayer 2.15.0

To minimize battery usage, does just_audio use audio offload when playing long streams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least as of 0.9.11, just_audio/ExoPlayer doesn't have any [Java code](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/blob/just_audio-v0.9.11/just_audio/android/src/main/java/com/ryanheise/just_audio/AudioPlayer.java) for offline scheduling under the hood or any [Dart API](https://pub.dev/documentation/just_audio/0.9.11/just_audio/just_audio-library.html) for turning it on, but you can make a [feature request](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/new/choose).